# border-radius breaking on google chrome

Tags: css, html

I'm having trouble finding a solution to this problem.
I have set up this small example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B9b2x/2/).

Google Chrome seems to break the border radius on *:hover* while Firefox renders it properly. What would be the correct approach to fix this?

`position:relative` in *.bubble* is probably the thing breaking it, if that's so is there any other solution to have the *.info* absolute position div nested to the *.bubble* so `top:` would use the top of the *.bubble* and not the page?

HTML:

```
<div class="bubble">
    <img src="http://oneslidephotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/Digital-SLR-Photography-All-in-One-For-Dummies-sample-image.jpg" />
    <div class="info">
        <h3>Some Info Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.info {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    width: inherit;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
    transition: top 0.2s ease-out;
    top:200px;
}

.bubble:hover .info {
    top:80px;
}

.info h3{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: Interesting. If you take off the transition, it doesn't break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the fact that you have an image taking up your whole background.

I've changed it so that you don't have an image (and reduced the border radius) ... so just basic border-radius, and of-course, things are fine:

```
<div class="bubble" style='border:solid 1px'>
    <div class="info">
        <h3>Some Info Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SbR6n/

Sounds like a bug.

Comment: I'd agree that this sounds like a bug.

Comment: Thanks for noting that the image might be causing the problem. Figured I could try doing it using css3 background like this. http://jsfiddle.net/B9b2x/8/

`background:url('http://oneslidephotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/Digital-SLR-Photography-All-in-One-For-Dummies-sample-image.jpg'); background-size:cover;` Thanks